# Placing text over an image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have the following code:

```
    var MARKER_PATH = 'https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/marker_green';
    var results_list = document.getElementById('list_results');
    var markerLetter = String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + i);
    var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH + markerLetter + '.png';

    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.style.backgroundColor = (i % 2 === 0 ? '#F0F0F0' : '#FFFFFF');

    var iconTd = document.createElement('td');
    var nameTd = document.createElement('td');
    var icon = document.createElement('img');

    icon.src = markerIcon;
    icon.setAttribute('class', 'placeIcon');
    icon.setAttribute('className', 'placeIcon');
    var name = document.createTextNode(result.name);
    iconTd.appendChild(icon);
    nameTd.appendChild(name);
    tr.appendChild(iconTd);
    tr.appendChild(nameTd);
    results_list.appendChild(tr);
```

[image]

This MARKER_PATH only has alphabet letters which is not enough for 60 items as it goes from A - Z.  I like to have numbers inside the markers.  I can create 60 images and load them locally, but that would be over killed with all those images.  Therefore,

I want to create only 1 image and place a numbers as a text over this image.  How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: @APerson, Thanks for editing.  I appreciate it

Comment: What about using the "new" label for [google.maps.Marker objects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#marker_labels)? (limited to a single character). Ah, but you want it in the "sidebar".  This question really doesn't have (much) to do with [google-maps-api-3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3).

Comment: @ geocodezip, thanks for the comment.  It's not different than what I have gotten so far.  A-Z is only 26 letters as I have 60 items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a class on the td with css background pointing to the image icon, then iterate like this,(you can run this snippet I created):

```js
var MARKER_PATH = 'https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/marker_green';
    var results_list = document.getElementById('list_results');
    var markerLetter = "";
  

var i;
for (i = 0; i < 60; i++) { 
  
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.style.backgroundColor = (i % 2 === 0 ? '#F0F0F0' : '#FFFFFF');

    var iconTd = document.createElement('td');
    var nameTd = document.createElement('td');
    

    
    iconTd.setAttribute('class', 'mybackground');
    
    
    var name = document.createElement('div');
    name.innerHTML = 's'+i;
  
  iconTd.innerHTML = ""+i;
  nameTd.innerHTML = "Title "+i;
    

    tr.appendChild(iconTd);
    tr.appendChild(nameTd);
  
    results_list.appendChild(tr);
  
  }
```

```css
td.mybackground{ 
background-image: url(http://www.whitehousewhitetails.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/google_pin.png); /* forward slash for the path */ 
width: 25px; /* use you own image size; */ 
height: 46px; /* use you own image size; */ 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: left top; 
text-align: center; 
vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 40px;
  color:blue;
  
}
```

```html
<table id="list_results" border="1">
<tr><td>img</td>
<td>description</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: Omg, you have saved my life.  I have spent all day staring at my code and falling asleep.  Although the numbers are huge, but I can play with them to make it right.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again.  I am having a little problem trying to place my local image to background-image.  in css, I use var image = 'marker_icon.png'; and it works.  I have tried to url(marker_icon.png); for this background-image, but it is not working.  Do you know how I can place my local image to this background-image?  Thanks a lot

Comment: The only possible problem is that the image is not on the same directory as the file you are executing...are you running the css code apart or on the same html page...and is the image located on the same folder of the html page?...PS: you dont have to use any var on the JS, just use the url on the CSS side (I forgot to remove that url link from the JS code)

Comment: I found a solution online.  For local images, use background: url (marker_list);  kinda strange, but it works. Thanks